# Passing query parameters to GET request (with request npm module)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this function below that is supposed to fetch data from a Twitch API Endpoint,
But I need to pass a query parameter with a key `to_id` and a value, and I don't know how to pass query parameters using this npm module,
I think I have to do this in the `gameOptions` object below,

(Here's a link of the doc: https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#requestoptions-callback)

```
function gameRequest(accessToken) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    const gameOptions = {
      url: "https://api.twitch.tv/helix/users/follows",
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Client-ID": MY_CLIENT_ID,
        Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken,
      },
    };
    if (!accessToken) {
      console.log("No Token");
    } else {
      console.log(gameOptions);

      const gameRequest = request.get(gameOptions, (err, res, body) => {
        if (err) {
          return console.log(err);
        }

        console.log(JSON.parse(body));
      });
    }
  }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: Try `url: "https://api.twitch.tv/helix/users/follows?to_id=" + yourID,`

Comment: thank you, it worked, I was looking for another way but I take this one

Comment: Note that this only works when your `yourID` variable doesn't contain any special characters. Make sure you URL encode the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can user `qs` in `gameOptions` :

```
const gameOptions = {
  url: "https://api.twitch.tv/helix/users/follows",
  method: "GET",
  qs : {
    "to_id" : valueToPass
  },
  headers: {
    "Client-ID": MY_CLIENT_ID,
    Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken,
  },
};
```